# Replacing 3-Way Light Switch with 4 wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I'm trying to replace an older style 3-way switch with a newer one. When I pulled the older one out, the wires weren't clamped down very well and 3 of the 4 (yes, 4) wires popped out of place before I had a chance to look and see what was where.

So, here's the situation.  I have 1 White, 1 Red, and 2 Blacks (we'll call them B1 & B2).

With the circuit breaker on and very carefully measuring voltages across each of the wires, I get the following.

```
W  <- 120V -> B1
W  <-   0V -> B2
W  <-  24V -> R
W  <-   0V -> Ground
B1 <- 120V -> B2
B1 <-  90V -> R
B1 <- 120V -> Ground  
B2 <-  24V -> R
B2 <-   0V -> Ground
R  <-  24V -> Ground
```

And also very carefully, if I touch the 2 black wires together, the light comes on.

So, my obvious question is, how do I need to wire these up to the new 3-way switch?

Thanks!

==============================

## Update

When I flip the other switch and re-check the voltages, they change to...

```
W  <-  24V -> B1
W  <-   0V -> B2
W  <- 120V -> R
W  <-   0V -> Ground
B1 <-  20V -> B2
B1 <-  94V -> R
B1 <-  24V -> Ground
B2 <- 120V -> R
B2 <-   0V -> Ground
R  <- 120V -> Ground
```

=========================

## Update #2

View of the back of the box
[image: view of the back of the box]

View of the sibling switch.
[image: view of the sibling switch]

===========================

## Update #3

Added Measurements above for all wires to ground for both above positions of the other switch.

Comment: Something funny is going on, because with normal switches & fixtures, you should see 0 & 120 but not anything in between. Depending on the type/sensitivity of your tester, it *might* (actually **hopefully**) be your tester. What, if anything, changes when you flip the other 3-way switch? That will help determine which wires are travelers between the two switches and which have other functions. Also, do all the wires come in to the box together or are they possibly grouped in some way (i.e., which would indicate wires together in a cable)?

Comment: Updated the question to answer your following @manassehkatz.

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the electrical box?

Comment: Added picture of the back of the box and another of how the other switch is wired up.

Comment: Looking at the intact switch, black is common, black and red are travelers.

That means black and red must be travelers on the first switch. Which black? The one that seems to "swap" with red when you flip the intact switch. That seems to be B1. We've still got the phantom (and I'm pretty sure they really are phantom) 20V & 90V. Can you (carefully!) measure the value from each wire to *ground* (the bare wires)? If things are wired correctly, ground should be very close to neutral, so that may give a better clue as to what is floating vs. coming from the panel.

Comment: And then what should I do with the white?  I believe it was connected to where the red one is in the other switch.

Comment: One step at a time. If the two switches were the same type (i.e., common in same location) then it would not make any sense for the white to have been connected to one of the travelers. But first let's see what, if anything, shows same as ground or 120V to ground. Test with the other switch in both positions. If you can get a non-contact tester that *might* help in identifying what is coming hot from the panel.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Added measurements to ground for all wires in both positions of the other switch.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Extra wire. Likely phantom voltages (but consistent). Only thing I'm pretty sure of is travelers = Red & "B1". Need to figure out overall wiring scheme of the two switches, light, incoming power, etc. White *should* be neutral but that normally wouldn't be on the switch. I'm confused. ThreePhaseEel may have a better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Identify the *travelers*

First, the partner switch is the power source.  You can tell because its **common** terminal is hooked directly off a dual receptacle.  Unless the receptacle is switched, that must be the supply.  The other two screws on the supply 3-way are the **travelers** and there is a black and red wire on them.   That is also consistent with the lamps being at the far end; since neutral would be present then, neutral must be white.  So that all jibes.

Your testing reveals that when you throw the switch, B1 and R wires alternate which one is hot.  So confirmed.

I am a big fan of marking wires with tape to indicate their function. I prefer to use yellow wire for both travelers, since it isn't useful to distinguish them from each other.  I would mark both travelers at both ends thusly.

There would be no use for any other wires to land on a traveler terminal.  The only remaining terminal is the "common", and assuming this is a 3-way, the remote common is the switched-hot wire going to the lamp.

I see a /3 cable (containing the travelers and a white) and a /2 cable on the left side of the switch box.

### Loads

Now, in the back of that box I see plain separation between the wires to the left switch, and the wires to the right switch.  With one exception: one neutral crosses over from this group to the other side. That shouldn't happen:  currents should always be equal in each cabLe, and that means a second wire would need to cross over too.  The house may be miswired.

Obviously B2 goes to the lamp.  But its partner white should be going to the white from the other 3-way, and that's not the case.  Now it would be proper if:

- the lamp was powered from the other box: in that the white wire from the /3 cable will tie to the common terminal, and carry switched-hot back to the other box, where it's tied to a cable to a lamp.  Or
- The /2 cable in this box went on to power a lamp, in which case the black wire from the /2 cable goes to common, and its white wire ties into the neutral brought over in the /3 cable.  (because of the equal currents rule, the neutral should not be poached from the neutral bundle in the right side of the box).

My working theory is that both of the above are true.  W carries switched-hot back to the other box in the /3, and the B2 is the hot from the /2 cable going on to a different lamp.  This circuit powers 2 lamps fed from both boxes.  Or did.  Since W is being used as a switched-hot, B2's partner white cannot return to it; instead they bootlegged neutral from the clump of cables serving the switch on the right. This is bad wiring and should be corrected one way or another.

If you don't see  where this second lamp would be, look for *switched receptacles* somewhere in the room.

Comment: You are correct about the 2 lamps.  The switches are by the front door and in the garage, and they activate the lights on the front porch and the driveway.